# Examples of Improved Virtual Queue

Tags: user-expectation

In the event of high demand traffic that can spike 100,000+ concurrent users, a queue is common to manage the flow of that traffic without crashing the site - these are common on sites like TicketMaster where millions of fans might be trying to buy tickets for Paul McCartney simultaneously.

The user is shown a spinning wheel and asked to wait for an unknown amount of time that can last anywhere from 30 seconds to 4 hours.

Are there any documented examples of better user experiences for large queues?

Comment: If you can give an accurate figure then I would imagine a message such as `There are 10,439 people ahead of you. Do not close your browser or else you will lose your place. Once it is your turn, you will have 10 minutes to complete your order. We apologize for the inconvenience but we are experiencing an extremely large flow of traffic at the moment.`

Comment: Or maybe don't put them in the queue right away but rather `There are x number of people in the queue, click Join to reserve your spot.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question! It reminded me of times when Google Reader went down and there were queues of  people waiting to upload their OPML's to various substitute services. I personally couldn't remember if Feedly had any kind of queue number ticket for users.

This looks quite good to me.

[image]

Another good option would be to give user a progress bar (that is, if system can predict the time of queue parsing).

Comment: this one along with "You should be near the front of the line in 2 hours 34 minutes"

Answer (score 2):

I would say look at automated call-in systems such as IVR's and use the best approaches from those. There are decades of user experience already there, and we know sort of what works and what doesn't.

Combine some IVR like concepts with the power of what a website can track and I think you could have a very powerful and friendly UX approach.

Some ideas

- Number ahead in queue
- Display Estimate for time to Transaction phase (Number ahead / Leave queue per minute)
- For long delays (say > 7 minutes) offer a message to alert when number is almost up (we will email/ text when your less than 5 minutes from ordering.

Much like an IVR, you could try to keep your user engaged at least somewhat. Where a call-in system often uses music, perhaps you could figure a way to engage or entertain your guests:

- A simple game while in the queue
- Facts about the queue "we are handling over 30 transactions a second, your up soon!" similar to what Windows does during an install (XP comes to mind for me)

[image]

These are my opinions, but there were too many random thoughts for just a comment.

Answer (score 1):

A queue of 1,000,000 is just rarely manageable in an interactive situation.

At some point the queue needs to cut bait.  There are only so many resources and a queue requires resources.

If the venue holds 300,000 and the there are 300,000 in the queue then the responsible response is "At this time we have more customers in the queue than seats.  Please check back later but most likely the show is sold out."

Don't put tickets for many cities on sale at the same time.

If you have reasonable expectation that you can address the request then give a best faith estimate of how long the wait is.  If certain sections are already sold out then tell them.

Consider phone support.  If everyone goes home at 4:00 and at 3:00 there at 10,000 in the queue I would rather be told to call back tomorrow then be put on hold until 4:00 and then be told we are closing for the day.

I am a developer.  A queue of 4 hours is just not manageable on a web server.  At 4 minutes you need to start cutting bait.  If there is revenue associated with the transaction then scale up - web farms are not expensive and not rocket science.  A person at the other end of the transaction is a whole different thing.

Comment: it's very hard to predict how many of those users will actually purchase a ticket so even if were are selling out a venue of 20,000 tickets and there are 1mm people on the site, it is very likely that only 10,000 of those will actually buy tickets.

Prematurely saying it's sold out is never a good idea.

Comment: @JoeIsaacson  No it is not hard.  It is called statistics.  If the first 400 bought X number of tickets then you calculate  within a confidence interval if Y how many tickets each call will purchase.  Really if the first 200,000 all bought an average of 4 tickets each and you have 100,000 left and 100,000 in the queue you would leave them on hold for 30 minutes when statistically there is less than 1 in a trillion chance you have a tickets for them.  After a 30 minutes wait to be told sorry sold out do consider that a good UX?  Do you think they will be likely to come back to your site?